# Java Naming - byte buffer reader/writer or input/output stream?

Tags: java, oop, naming-conventions, readability

Looking through a couple different projects I can see two different namings for the same items.

Which one is correct/wrong or is more universally understood vs the other?

Project 1:

```
//reading
byte[] data;
InputStream is = new InputStream(data);
int value = is.getUnsignedByte();

//writing
OutputStream os = new OutputStream(16); //arg0 = capacity (not revelant here)
os.writeByte(value);
```

Project 2:

```
//reading
byte[] data;
ByteBufReader reader = new ByteBufReader(data);
int value = reader.getUnsigned(DataType.BYTE, DataOrder.REGULAR);

//writing
ByteBufBuilder builder = new ByteBufBuilder(16); //arg0 = capacity (not revelant here)
builder.put(DataType.BYTE, DataOrder.REGULAR, value);
```

Comment: That's not just naming, those classes likely do very different things. Have you checked over their documentation?

Comment: Yes, and they do the exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

Neither of classes is a class in the Java SE class library.

- There is no `ByteBufReader` class.
- There is an `InputStream` class, but its API is not compatible with the way your code is using it, some *this* class must be a different one.

Which is more correct?  It really depends on what the actual classes do, and you haven't shown us the classes.

However, using the name `InputStream` is a mistake, no matter its "correctness".  It is a bad idea to choose a class name that is the same as a common class name.  It is bad for readability.  And in this case, there are *three* existing `InputStream` classes ... in the Java 8 class library.

But to be honest, it looks like the code you are looking at should be using the existing (standard) `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` classes.

Comment: Here both classes buffReader and InputStream represent a modified version of   "org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream"   (which does not extend or implement any existing Java class, but does essentially the same thing).

Comment: That's not sufficient to answer your question.  (And doesn't make a lot of sense ...)  Please provide a link to the code ... or the javadoc if the javadoc is written properly.